# JSON-LD Schema.org event info not being pulled into Google

Tags: seo, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I have a handful of WordPress websites that use **The Events Calendar** for displaying events that are open to the public.

I notice if I type a cities name and then the word event, that our website is not being pulled in to the special section that appear. Google uses its **Knowledge Graph**. I was looking through the source code and noticed that our sites uses JSON-LD, generated from the information used for the event, one of the methods Google talks about using, but don’t understand why our site information isn’t being shown.

These sites have been up a year and get 3k visits a month so they're being indexed fairly regularly.

I was looking through the event properties JSON-LD, and I noticed the entire event address (street, city, state zip) gets put inside the `name` property of the Place or Postal array ([Heres a screenshot of my sites schema](https://cloudup.com/czYdaHgfjUS)). When I look up other events that are pulled into Google, they list the those attributes in the `address` properties ([Screenshot of other site’s schema](https://cloudup.com/cEKPjtpq7Hj)).

I think because the address is put into the `name` property instead of the `address` property, that Google might not be showing the events. Has anybody else seen this happen with their sites? Or is something else wrong with the sites we set up?

Comment: can you post the rest of the data around PostalAddress, the blue box hides some of it and there is a warning but the description of the warning is missing. You could look at adding GeoCoordinates to refine the location further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your events are marked up using the Google example, but ***I  believe* this is wrong**:

https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/events

```
  "location" : {
    "@type" : "Place",
    "sameAs" : "http://www.hi-dive.com",
    "name" : "The Hi-Dive",
    "address" : "7 S. Broadway, Denver, CO 80209"
  }
```

**2019 edit**: The markup and URL above have since changed and match what is expected from the testing tool.

In order for your sites structured data to match that other event you have a screen shot of, you will need to adjust your JSON-LD to the way it's presented on [schema.org](http://schema.org), which uses PostalAddress and narrows down a little bit more:

https://schema.org/location (and https://schema.org/PostalAddress) - Click the JSON-LD example tabs

```
     "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "Withworth Institute",
        "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "addressLocality": "Seattle",
          "addressRegion": "WA",
          "postalCode": "98052",
          "streetAddress": "20341 Whitworth Institute 405 N. Whitworth"
        },
        "url": "wells-fargo-center.html"
      }
```

I can't say for certain if this is the primary reason for your issue but I do think you should follow the schema.org approach either way. Even the Structured Data Tool per your screenshots seems to indicate that it's looking for postalAddress even though Google doesn't use that in the example.. perhaps that article is outdated.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted a second opinion just to be sure, this schema is generated by the events calendar plugin for wordpress and I have yet to find the source file that generates it. Once i find that, i can alter it and see if theres any change.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that a migration to JSON-LD from inline RDFa style schema, which validates 100% using their new rich snippet validator tool no longer shows Review stars in search results. They've also taken away the ability to see stars validate using old style RDFa schema validation.

This could be an issue with the search team not talking to the developers responsible for the structured data and schema tools, rolling out disjointed feature upgrades. Their recommended use of JSON-LD will likely have a negative impact on display in search in the near term if you'd like to see additional meta data populate in search results pages.

If meta data in search results is a firm requirement you could roll off your JSON-LD module and use a module with the older RDFa or microdata implementation inline in your HTML. Hopefully this will be remedied soon.